# Google AppScript change date format

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a date in this format '2018-07-18 20:20:27' which in Google App Script I need to change to format 'dd MMM yyyy' so that I get '18 Jul 2018.

I tried the following:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date('2018-07-18 20:20:27'), 'Etc/GMT', 'dd MMM yyyy'));
```

But that just gives me: 01 Jan 1970
all the time, not the date that I have passed in. Does anyone know where im going wrong?

Comment: What does `Logger.log(new Date(''))` give you? Is the date object created properly?

Comment: it gives me: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970. I think the problem is the time with : in between hours min and secs, im gonna try using substring to get rid of the time then try it

Comment: This does the job, but going to leave this open incase someone can find a better way of doing it. 
  var a = '2018-07-18 20:20:27'
  var c = new Date(a.substr(0,10))
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(c, 'GMT', 'dd MMM yyyy')
  
  Logger.log(a);
  Logger.log(c);
  Logger.log(d);

Comment: Maybe try `var c = new Date(a.replace(' ',"T"))`

Comment: nope that doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to dealing with older JavaScript and `Date.parse` :). Format your input datestring to use the ISO date and time separator.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have managed to do it so far is this:

```
var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(rawExport[0][1].substr(0,10)), 'GMT', 'dd MMM yyyy')
```

This works but not very pretty

Comment: Try to avoid hardcoding the time zone, use Session.getScriptTimeZone() instead.  This will prevent daylight savings issues.

Comment: Great suggestion thanks, updated my script with this.